# how I can make a menu with a second level with angular, typescript, ionic

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, sass

does anyone know how I can make a menu with a second level? but with the same menu that I have, like this:

**only settings have more options and only the names of the menu are changed and each one must lead to its page content**

[image]

if I click on the settings option, the "new menu" appears with the options that have settings

> app.component.ts

```
initializeApp () {
    this.appPages.push({
      title: 'Home',
      url: '/home',
      // icon: 'home-outline',
      image: 'assets/images/menu/home.svg',
      color: 'success'
    })
    this.appPages.push({
      title: 'Profile',
      url: '/profile',
      // icon: 'person-outline',
      image: 'assets/images/menu/profile.svg',
      color: 'tertiary'
    })
    this.appPages.push({
      title: 'Settings',
      url: '/settings',
      // icon: 'settings-outline',
      image: 'assets/images/menu/enter.svg',
      color: 'gray-light'
    })
  }
```

> //app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'settings',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsModule)
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
]
```

> // app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="maincontent" [when]="showSplitPane && false">
    <ion-menu swipe-gesture="false" contentId="maincontent" id="mainmenu" menuId="mainmenu" type="overlay">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index; let l = last; let f = first">
            <ion-item (click)="selectedIndex = i" routerDirection="root" (click)="navigate(p.url)" lines="none"
              detail="false" [color]="p.color" [class]="{'ion-margin-vertical': !l && ! f}">
              <ion-icon *ngIf="p.icon" slot="start" [icon]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-icon *ngIf="p.image" slot="start" [icon]="p.image"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label class="lighter" [class.bold]="selectedIndex == i">{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
              <ion-icon class="ion-no-margin" icon="chevron-forward-sharp" color="black"></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="maincontent" maincontent></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: Did you check this example? https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/app/menu-nested-example.ts

Comment: @AliBektash sorry, the link sends me to the main page of stackblitz :(

Comment: use nested `<ion-router-outlet id="menu-content"></ion-router-outlet>`

Comment: @ALAINTORRES Sorry for my inconvenience https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples#menu-nested

Comment: hi @NajamUsSaqib , and where do I declare the 3 settings options?

Comment: @AliBektash hi, thank u for your example, but I don't know how to implement it with what I already have :(

Comment: @ALAINTORRES inside `settings.routing.module.ts` create child routes.